# Как в Selenium использовать функции из подключенных js скриптов

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Использую Selenium на Python. Есть сайт с подключенными js скриптами в теге script.
Так вот при попытке запустить функцию из одного из подключенных js файлов с помощью питоновской функции execute_script происходит ошибка:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: loadModel is not defined
```

Подозреваю что селениум по каким-то причинам не подгружает эти файлы.
Вот как запускаю скрипт:

```
self._driver.execute_script("loadModel(\'%s\', \'\', \'%s\');" % (web3d, zone))
```

И подключение драйвера:

```
def __init__(self, data, conf):
    self._conf = conf
    self._data = data
    self._setup_driver()
    self._load_page()
    self._len = len(self._data)
    self._run()
    return

def _setup_driver(self):
    d_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
    service = Service(d_path)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    self._driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    
def _load_page(self):
    self._driver.get(url="http://player-inner-server")
```